# Proving $n+3 \mid 3n^3-11n+48$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, proof-writing

I'm really stuck while I'm trying to prove this statement:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\quad (n+3) \mid  (3n^3-11n+48)$.

I couldn't even how to start.

Comment: The statement is false as written: for $n=1$, for instance, it’s not true that $40\mid 4$. I suspect that you mean $$n+3\mid 3n^3-11n+48\;.$$ $m\mid n$ means that $m$ divides $n$, i.e., that $n=km$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant to write *does not* divide (vs. divides). Then it is true (and less trivial than the alternative reversed interpretation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you’re actually trying to prove that $n+3$ divides $3n^3-11n+48$, you can always simply do a polynomial long division:

$$\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
&&&&&3n^2&-&9n&+&16\\ \hline
n&+&3&3n^3&&&-&11n&+&48\\
&&&3n^3&+&9n^2\\ \hline
&&&&&-9n^2&-&11n\\
&&&&&-9n^2&-&27n\\ \hline
&&&&&&&16n&+&48\\
&&&&&&&16n&+&48\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

There’s no remainder, so

$$3n^3-11n+48=(n+3)(2n^2-9n+16)\;.$$

Comment: +1 simply for having the patience to mathjax that calculation

Answer (score 4):

To expand on caveman's answer:  Note that [**polynomial long division**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Example) works well here:

Dividing $$3n^3 - 11n + 48 \tag{dividend}$$ by $\;(n + 3)\;\;\text{(divisor)},\;$ gives a *quotient* of $$3n^2 - 9n + 16\tag{quotient}$$

and leaves a remainder of $0$.
$$\text{That is, }\quad\quad\frac{3n^3 - 11n + 48}{n+3} = \;3n^2 -9n + 16 $$ $$ \iff \;\;(n+3)(3n^2 - 9n + 16) = 3n^3 - 11n + 48$$

The result of dividing $\,(3n^3 - 11n + 48)\,$ by $\,(n+ 3)\,$, where $n$ is ANY $n \in \mathbb N$, gives an integer quotient: $\;n^2 - 9n + 16$, with no remainder.

$$\text{Therefore, we have }\quad (n+3)\mid (3n^3 - 11n + 48) \iff (3n^3 = 11n + 48) \equiv 0 \pmod {n+3}$$

Answer (score 4):

There are two routine ways to see this:

1. Do the polynomial long division $(3n^3 -11n + 48) / (n+3)$ and check that the remainder is $0$.
2. A polynomial $f(n)$ is divisible by $(n - a)$ if and only if $f(a) = 0$. So in this example, $f(n) = 3n^3 -11n + 48$. Plugging $a = -3$ into $f$ we get $f(-3) = 0$, which shows that $f(n)$ is divisible by $(n - (-3)) = (n + 3)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrote it backwards by accident then the proof is by

$$(3n^2 - 9n + 16)(n+3) = 3n^3 - 11n + 48$$

---

if you meant what you wrote then $n=0\;$ gives a counter examples since $48$ doesn't divide $3$.

Comment: @caveman I mean |

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $3*(-3)^3-11*(-3)+48=-81+33+48=0$.